# Use 12V to 240V inverter to supply 240V power to a transformer

Tags: transformer, inverter

My gate opener was connect to a 240V power outlet on the wall through a AC 240V to AC 16V transformer. The gate opener has a 12V battery inside. This is specification of the gate opener:
Motor: 120 Watt 12v DC
Transformer: 16v AC 1 Amp
Battery change voltage: 13.8v DC

Few weeks ago, the 240v power outlet on the wall was broken and cannot provide power anymore.
It is the only 240 power outlet near by the gate and very difficult to replace the cable because it is placed under ground.

One work around soultion I planed is to connect a converter (Input AC 240V, Output DC 12V,2.8A) to another 240V power outlet in the house, then extend the 12V power out put through a heavy duty garden electrical cable to the gate. Then, connect the cable to a DC 12V to AC 240V (1000W) inverter. Then connect the inverter's output to the gate opener's transformer (AC 240V 24W to AC 16V 1A).

It looks working for me, but will this cause higher electricity cost as the inverter will run at all the time. Is this a feasible solution? any damage to the gate opener??

[image]

Comment: why `DC 12V to AC 240V`? ... why not `DC 12V to AC 16V`?

Comment: 240v to 16v transformer is fixed connect to the opener. If use DC12V to AC16V, have to cut off the connection of the trnasformer.

Comment: I do think you should depict something, as I don't quite understand.

Comment: `Is this a feasible solution?` it is unknown ... the problem is unclear ... as @MarkoBuršič says, please provide a diagram of the gate system

Comment: @SolomonSlow, 12V line will be on the top of the ground.

Comment: I don't see why you need to transform 240VAC to 12VDC and then back to 240VAC and then to 16VAC. Why not 240VAC to 16VAC as before?  You'd better dig and place hose also for latter use. Also, don't understand how a 240VAC, as you call it "power supply" can broke.

Comment: @Marko. Thanks. It is 240v AC power outlet on the wall. The problem is how the 240V cable is placed undergroud. It is a old house.

Comment: Hi Jsotola, is there a DC 12v to AC 16V transformer in the market?

Comment: What about to move to the next 240VAC outlet, connect the transfrormer 240/16 and put a cable, as you mentioned? Instead of using 12V extensina cable, you drive it with 16VAC.

Comment: @Marko, thanks. Can I use 12V exntension cable to extend 16V AC output?

Comment: @leilei yes you can run 16v AC on the extension cable, but one more question that needs to be answered. How long is the extension cable?

Comment: @thisjt, thanks. the extension cable is 30m long

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of cable I can use to transfer AC 16V power output?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/593363/what-kind-of-cable-i-can-use-to-transfer-ac-16v-power-output)