# Is it ok to extend 16V AC output with 12V heavy duty electrical cable?

Tags: transmission-line

I have a AC 240V to AC 16V transformer to drive my gate opener. But the 240V power outlet is far from the gate. Is it ok to extend 16V AC output by using 12V heavy duty electrical cable?

Transformer: AC 16V, 1A

Comment: Yes, it is okay. A cable used for 12V AC or DC and it is heavy duty, right? Don't extend AC 240V, but use 16V for the distant gate opener. If you can, put a fuse inline between the transformer and where the cable connects. If possible make sure the transformer 240V and 16V sides are isolated.

Comment: @Jay Thanks. Yes. It is heavy duty cable for gardening light. How many amperes of fuse should I use？

Comment: That cable sounds good enough, since it was already for outdoor use, I assume the gate opener uses something like [this](https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/mighty-mule-e-z-gates-18-v-replacement-transformer-for-ul-series-automatic-gate-openers-3609887?cm_mmc=organic_feed-_-GoogleShopping-_-Product-_-3609887), I would start with 1A slow-blow. Gate opener coil should take only a few hundred mA.

Comment: Just be careful to use lightning protection on *any* long cable run outside.

Comment: I assume the opener contains a magnetic latch and a motor to open and close the gate. There will be a fuse built in, so you just need to connect it. If the transformer came with it, the output will be adequately isolated from the mains.

Comment: @PeterR.McMahon, the fuse is to prevent problems happening on the cable, as well as the load (motor or solenoid). If something happens, the source has to cut the power for the safety.

Comment: Thanks guys. @jay, so I need a AC circuit fuse between the transformer and the gate opener. right?

Comment: Yes, you need to put a fuse right after the transformer. 16V/2A is 32W, a good power to cook something. If you know the gate opener electrical spec, use 1.5x larger fuse, slow-blow. Otherwise start from 1A fuse.

Comment: @jay, thanks. is this fuse used to prevent the short circuit on the cable between gate opener and transformer?

Comment: Yes lei. And in case the cable gets old, and you've moved to a college dome, and your cat at home got tangled to the cable on a rainy day, I would feel less sorry, if the fuse helped any. :-)

Comment: @jay, should the fuse be close to gate opener or transformer? I guess is gate opener because the transformer supports short circuit protection feature.

Comment: @leilei Fuse is located close to the transformer, so, if any problem happens beyond the transformer, the power cuts from the source (transformer) side.

Comment: @leilei  try to make a moisture proof connection as high humidity corrodes copper.  Many  tapes do not give a gas-tight seal. Perhaps plumbers tape over solder or a crimped or terminal block screw connection under sufficient torque.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of cable I can use to transfer AC 16V power output?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/593363/what-kind-of-cable-i-can-use-to-transfer-ac-16v-power-output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use 12V to 240V inverter to supply 240V power to a transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594048/use-12v-to-240v-inverter-to-supply-240v-power-to-a-transformer)

Comment: While I understand the sharing of information and the human connections being made through discussion, the off-topic discussion has become longer than the [on-topic use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). So the discussion has been moved to chat (see link below) and should be continued in chat for any future off-topic messages too. Future off-topic *comments* may be deleted without notice. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131267/discussion-on-question-by-lei-lei-is-it-ok-to-extend-16v-ac-output-with-12v-heav).